# How to pull up check-in history report in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Using TFS how to get check-in history report by each developer in team? I do not have full admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Right click a folder in Source Control Explorer and Choose View History.  The History is typically displayed for a particular folder/path, not a particular user.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a report that I can upload to Excel. And also I wanted to see numbers of lines per developer.

Comment: No such capability exists out of the box.  You could write your own SSRS report against the TFS data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the easiest thing to do would be to download and install [TFS Side Kicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2010).

1. Use the History SideKick and then get the history of the branch/user that you need.
2. You can use the Username as a filter criteria.
3. Use the save button as shown in the image to save as a CSV file. This would get you the data in Excel and from there you can play around with it.

[image]

This will only give you the default History information, not number of lines etc.

Second option - as mentioned in the [LINK](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html) and as Dylan Smith mentioned above to make use of custom reports. For that you would need access to the TFS data tier and be able to pull data from the TFS sql server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured the reporting integration, you can connect to the SSAS Cube from Excel to extract the changeset information. Look for "Version Control Changeset" in the list of pivot fields.

You can also use the "Code Churn" information to get the number of lines added/modified/deleted